# Почему при превышении размера символьного массива и передаче его в функцию не возникает ошибка?

Tags: c++, массивы, char

Когда отправляю символьный массив размера 20 в функцию, которая принимает символьный массив размером до 5, не срабатывает ошибка, вроде того, что размер превышен, или что нибудь подобное. Он пропускает и при этом он принимает всю строку, а не только первые 5 символов.

Почему это происходит?

```
#include <iostream>

#define DL_FIO 20

using namespace std;
void checkup(char str[20], int* fl);
int main()
{
    int k;
    char word[DL_FIO];
    cin >> word;
    int f1 = 1;
    checkup(word, &f1);
    cout << word;
}
void checkup(char str[5], int* fl)
{
    cout << str[9];
    int x, i, n, flag1 = 1;
    //для цифр
    if (*fl != 0)
    {
        for (n = 0; n < 5; n++)
        {
            if ((str[n] >= 'a' && str[n] <= 'z') || (str[n] >= 'A' && str[n] <= 'Z'))flag1 = 0;
        }
        while (strlen(str) > 5 || flag1 == 0)
        {
            puts("\nOnly numeral can be entered. Try again.");
            cin>>str;
            flag1 = 1;
            for (n = 0; n < 5; n++)
            {
                if ((str[n] >= 'a' && str[n] <= 'z') || (str[n] >= 'A' && str[n] <= 'Z'))flag1 = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    //для фамилии
    else
    {
        for (n = 0; n < DL_FIO; n++)
        {
            if (str[n] >= '0' && str[n] <= '9')flag1 = 0;
        }
        while (strlen(str) > DL_FIO || flag1 == 0)
        {
            puts("\nOnly letters can be entered. Try again.");
            cin>>str;
            flag1 = 1;
            for (n = 0; n < DL_FIO; n++)
            {
                if (str[n] >= '0' && str[n] <= '9')flag1 = 0;
            }
        }
        (*fl)++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Потому что типы неявно приводятся к общему - `char*`. Чтобы контролировать размер массива, можно использовать шаблонный тип [std::array](https://ideone.com/2c2dc7)

Comment: Только массив не символический, а символьный...

Answer (score 8):

В объявлениях вида

```
void checkup(char str[20], int* fl);
```

размер массива не имеет никакого значения и никак не учитывается языком. Все объявления параметров типа "массив" в языках C и C++ всегда сразу автоматически трансформируются в параметры типа "указатель".

Ваше вышепроцитированное объявление эквивалентно объявлениям

```
void checkup(char str[123], int* fl);
void checkup(char str[], int* fl);
```

и в конечном итоге все они эквивалентны объявлению

```
void checkup(char *str, int* fl);
```

Никакого контроля размера массива тут нет и быть не может.

Если в языке С++ вы хотите потребовать от вызывающего кода передачи массива какого-то однозначно заданного размера, то передавайте ваш массив по ссылке

```
void checkup(char (&str)[20], int* fl);
```

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы понять почему так происходит достаточно посмотреть в скомпилированной проге ее функции. Вот что вывел `nm`:

```
0000000000004060 B __bss_start
0000000000004298 b completed.7325
                 U __cxa_atexit@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 w __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000004050 D __data_start
0000000000004050 W data_start
00000000000010e0 t deregister_tm_clones
0000000000001150 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000003db8 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
0000000000004058 D __dso_handle
0000000000003dc0 d _DYNAMIC
0000000000004060 D _edata
00000000000042a0 B _end
00000000000014d4 T _fini
0000000000001190 t frame_dummy
0000000000003da8 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
0000000000002224 r __FRAME_END__
0000000000004000 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000001458 t _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
                 w __gmon_start__
000000000000206c r __GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
0000000000001000 t _init
0000000000003db8 t __init_array_end
0000000000003da8 t __init_array_start
0000000000002000 R _IO_stdin_used
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
00000000000014d0 T __libc_csu_fini
0000000000001470 T __libc_csu_init
                 U __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000001195 T main
                 U puts@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000001110 t register_tm_clones
00000000000010b0 T _start
                 U strlen@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000004060 D __TMC_END__
000000000000140f t __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)
00000000000011e4 T checkup(char*, int*)
                 U std::ios_base::Init::Init()@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U std::ios_base::Init::~Init()@@GLIBCXX_3.4
0000000000004180 B std::cin@@GLIBCXX_3.4
0000000000004060 B std::cout@@GLIBCXX_3.4
0000000000002008 r std::piecewise_construct
0000000000004299 b std::__ioinit
                 U std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char)@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator>><char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char*)@@GLIBCXX_3.4
```

обратите внимание на 38 строчку:

```
00000000000011e4 T checkup(char*, int*)
```

Тобишь ваша функция принимает `char *` а не `char[5]` или `char[20]` хотя это и разные типы (но `char[n]` автоматом приводится к `char *`). Таким образом компилятор не видит никакой разницы между определением и реализацией этих функций (вы можете попробовать реализовать две функции принимаещией `char[5]` и `char[20]` и компилятор ругнется на то, что функции не могут иметь одинаковых сигнатур при том же названии)